# Rear wheel tilted on the trainer

Tags: turbo-trainer

My bike is Giant Defy 5 and trainer is Elite Rampa. I notice that after putting my bike on the trainer and riding for a while, the rear wheel tilts to one side, usually resulting in the wheel rubs the brake and even frame. I do not have this problem outside. Is there something wrong with my trainer setup? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Do you have to replace your standard quick-release and use a trainer specific quick-release? A tilting wheel indicates that the QR isn't tight enough. Tighten the right nut by 1/8 to 1/4 of a turn.

Comment: Yes. I already use the skewer comes with the trainer. I will try to tighten it a little more. The right nut is the driver side? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, opposite the cam/lever of the QR. You open the lever tighten the nut slightly and close the lever again. Basically the same you'd do if you put in a wheel.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any reason that would be migrating in the frame unless it wasn't secured enough to begin with.  You should check the tightness of your quick release.

Comment: How to adjust a quick release https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hcq-PwYj3TE